# Set Thumbanail mp3 Song Thumbnail image to my imageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to set my MP3 song thumbnail image to my Imageview;

i have an song array that contains 5 songs. i want to set the first song thumbnail to my Imageview.

my array is this

```
mp3Array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"song",@"song1",@"song2",@"song3",@"song4", nil];
```

Crash at this line

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [song valueForProperty:
                                       MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
```

Crash log is

**erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString valueForProperty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dd0**

I tried this code to set thumbnail but not set thumbnail crash the app.

code is below...

```
  MPMediaItem * song=[mp3Array objectAtIndex:delegate.count];

    UIImage *image = nil;

    MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [song valueForProperty:
                                       MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    if(itemArtwork != nil)

        image = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100,100)];

[imgView setImage:image];
```

where may i wrong.

help me out this...

thanks in advance..

Comment: can you say *which line* has the crash and what the crash looks like in the console? you say there are "five songs" but I only count four songs names in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  Here is your problem: your array appears to have NSString objects in them:

```
mp3Array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"song",@"song1",@"song2",@"song3",@"song4", nil];
```

These need to be `MPMediaItem` objects if you want to be able to retrieve `MPMediaItem` objects and not `NSString` objects from the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `UIImage *image = nil;`, then there is no ivar `image`. Replace that line with `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];`. Because of that, you will be able to set the image with `imagewithSize` after the `if`-statement.